# jquery ajax start handler not firing

Tags: jquery, ajax

jquery ajax start handler not firing. Why?
**jquery 1.6.2**

Code example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#rr-loading-overlay').ajaxStart(function(){
  alert('asda');
 }).ajaxStop(function(){

 });

 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'service.com',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
     formatData(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     alert(textStatus + ' / ' + errorThrown);
    }
 });

    function formatData(data){
 }

})
```

also i tried and nothing.

```
 $(document').ajaxStart(function(){
   alert('asda');

     })
```

Comment: Does `#rr-loading-overlay` actually match anything?

Comment: @Frederic - He says he tried with $(document) also.

Comment: @Shankar, you're right, I didn't see past the mismatched quote :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jUwDj/)

Answer (score 2):

I had run into same problem. What worked for me was binding `ajaxStart` **before making any AJAX request**